# How can I convert an Object to Json in a Rabbit reply?

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have two applications communicating with each other using rabbit.

I need to send (from app1) an object to a listener (in app2) and after some process (on listener) it answer me with another object, now I am receiving this error:
`ClassNotFound`

I am using this config for rabbit in both applications:

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitConfiguration {

    public final static String EXCHANGE_NAME = "paymentExchange";

    public final static String EVENT_ROUTING_KEY = "eventRoute";
    public final static String PAYEMNT_ROUTING_KEY = "paymentRoute";

    public final static String QUEUE_EVENT = EXCHANGE_NAME + "." + "event";
    public final static String QUEUE_PAYMENT = EXCHANGE_NAME + "." + "payment";
    public final static String QUEUE_CAPTURE = EXCHANGE_NAME + "." + "capture";

    @Bean
    public List<Declarable> ds() {
        return queues(QUEUE_EVENT, QUEUE_PAYMENT);
    }

    @Autowired
    private ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory;

    @Bean
    public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() {
        return new RabbitAdmin(rabbitConnectionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectExchange exchange() {
        return new DirectExchange(EXCHANGE_NAME);
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
        RabbitTemplate r = new RabbitTemplate(rabbitConnectionFactory);
        r.setExchange(EXCHANGE_NAME);
        r.setChannelTransacted(false);
        r.setConnectionFactory(rabbitConnectionFactory);
        r.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
        return r;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    private List<Declarable> queues(String... nomes) {
        List<Declarable> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < nomes.length; i++) {
            result.add(newQueue(nomes[i]));
            if (nomes[i].equals(QUEUE_EVENT))
                result.add(makeBindingToQueue(nomes[i], EVENT_ROUTING_KEY));
            else
                result.add(makeBindingToQueue(nomes[i], PAYEMNT_ROUTING_KEY));
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static Binding makeBindingToQueue(String queueName, String route) {
        return new Binding(queueName, DestinationType.QUEUE, EXCHANGE_NAME, route, null);
    }

    private static Queue newQueue(String nome) {
        return new Queue(nome);
    }

}
```

I send the message using this:

```
String response = (String) rabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(RabbitConfiguration.EXCHANGE_NAME,
            RabbitConfiguration.PAYEMNT_ROUTING_KEY, domainEvent);
```

And await for a response using a cast to the object.

This communication is between two different applications using the same rabbit server.

How can I solve this?

I expected rabbit convert the message to a json in the send operation and the same in the reply, so I've created the object to correspond to a json of reply.

Comment: this is my config for listener:
`@Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory() {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(rabbitConnectionFactory);
        factory.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
        return factory;
    }`

Answer (score 4):

Show, please, the configuration for the listener. You should be sure that `ListenerContainer` there is supplied with the `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter` as well to carry `__TypeId__` header back with the reply.

Also see Spring AMQP JSON [sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp-samples/tree/master/spring-rabbit-json) for some help.